# How do I make my profile image on mobile responsive in landscape?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

When I view my created website in landscape on my mobile (Samsung S10), the profile image becomes way too large for the position it is in and covers the navigation bar. How do I make the image responsive in a landscape view where it is smaller and doesn't cover the navigation bar.

```
.profile-image {
  height: 750px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 72%;
  transform: translateX(-72%);

 @media (max-width:1000px){
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .profile-image{
    height: 460px;
    left: 90%;
    transform: translateX(-90%);
  }

@media(min-width:1000px){
  .profile-image{
    height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 90%;
    transform: translateX(-90%);
  }
}

@media(min-width:750px){
  .profile-image{
    left: 90%;
  }
}

@media(max-width:750px){
  section{
    background-image:none;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
  }

  .profile-image{
    display: none;
  }
```

Have a look at it live on github: https://derrickogole.github.io/portfolio-website-derrick-ogole-demo/

Comment: Show us your HTML please

Comment: <!--Model-->

            <img src="images/portfolio-profile-image-no-bg.png" class="profile-image" alt="profile-image">

Answer (score 0):

Use `orientation CSS media feature`

Media queries can also be used to change the layout of a page depending on the orientation of the browser. You can have a set of CSS properties that will only apply when the browser window is wider than its height, a so-called "Landscape" orientation.

[More In W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { 
   /* Code For Portrait */
 }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { 
  /* Code For Landscape */
 }
```

```css
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { 
  h1{ color:blue; }
 }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { 
  h1{ color: red; }
 }
```

```html
<h1>I'm Red If orientation is landscape else I'm blue</h1>
```